# Javascript function from outher scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, shadow

Hey guys I am new to JavaScript and I have a question.
I have validator.js file in which I validate email, password, and requests.
Here is it

```
/**
 * Simple regex validator for email
 * @param email The email
 * @returns {boolean} Whether the email matches the regex
 */
function email(email) {
    const regExp = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return regExp.test(email);

}

/**
 * Simple regex validator for password
 * @param password The password
 * @returns {boolean} Whether the password matches the regex
 */
function password(password) {
    const regExp = /^(?=.*\d).{7,15}$/;
    return regExp.test(password);
}

const request = {
    email: {
        message: '',
        validate: function (req) {
            const email = req.body.email;
            if(!email){
                email.message = 'Email is required';
                return false;
            }
            if(!validator(email(email))){
                email.message = 'Email is not valid';
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
};

module.exports = {
    email,
    password,
    request
};
```

I want to use email(email) function in email's validate function but I have variable shadowing, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't have two things with the same name? E.g. rename email to validateEmail?

Comment: Don't use variable names that shadow function names. Change one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a shadowed variable directly. Not unless you have some other handle to that value.

The best solution is simply not to shadow.

Either, change the name of your email address variable:

```
const emailAddress = req.body.email;
```

Or change the name of your email validation function:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
```

Or better yet, do both for clarity.

---

Here's what I mean by "some other handle".

```
function email(email) { /* ... */ }
function password(password) { /* ... */ }

const validators = { email, password }

function doStuff() {
  const email = req.body.email;
  validators.email(email)
}
```

In this case, we've shadowed the local variable `email`, but we have assign the email function to another object, which we can still access.

There are a lot of ways to do this, depending on how you are structuring your codebase.

---

But, in general, shadowing is bad, and you should do your best to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought of this option, but I was also interested if there is a way to do so. Now I know that there is not. Thx.

Comment: Update my answer with an example of how you get around showing by setting up another way to get what you want.

Comment: I also think that there is a better way of validating request's body, creating a general function like validate(propertyName,validatorFunc), which will do the stuff I wrote in validate's function.But this is not concerned to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest a solution like this, which I think is better cause it generalizes the request's body validation.

```
const request = {
    body: function(propertyName,func){
        this.message = '';
        this.validate = function(req){
            const propertyValue = req.body[propertyName];
            if(!propertyValue){
                this.message = `${propertyName} is required`
                return false;
            }
            if(!func(propertyValue)){
                this.message = `${propertyName} is not valid`
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    },
};
```